# Regex to replace link inside img tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to replace the URL inside the `img` tag using regex. Problem i'm facing is when i have 2 img tags it converts the String to one `img` tag. Below is the Example and Regex I tried.
Regex : `(?<=src=\").*?(?<=(?i)new).*?(?=\")`

Original String

```
String content = "This is the content with img tags <img src=\"https://link/img.jpeg\"> and <img src=\"https://link/img_new.jpeg\">"; 
SYSO(content.replaceAll("(?<=src=\").*?(?<=(?i)new).*?(?=\")","SECOND_IMG").replaceAll("(?<=src=\").*?(?<=(?i)link).*?(?=\")","FIRST_IMG"));
```

Output:

```
This is the content with img tags <img src="SECOND_IMG">
```

But the desired output is

```
This is the content with img tags <img src="FIRST_IMG"> and <img src="SECOND_IMG">
```

Comment: For brevity could you explain the working of the two `replaceAll()`s?

Comment: @CoffeehouseCoder I want to replace URL with 2 different strings according to some condition

Comment: I believe using regex to identify and replace urls is always troublesome.

Comment: You should use xml parser for this task. There are plenty of them bundled with Java EE.

Comment: Don’t use regular expressions for this.  [Here’s why.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg)

Comment: The second parameter to regex used for search the end of the input.

Comment: [H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/4032703)